# EntityFrameworkCore Key column auto increment from specific value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

A simple class with an auto-incremented `Key` column

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Key]
    public long SomeClassId { get; set;}
}
```

Normally the `SomeClassId` will start and auto-increment from 1. Is there anyway to force the ID to start from a specific number, say 10001?

It was suggested [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2062551.aspx?Entity%20Framework%20How%20to%20set%20a%20start%20value%20for%20an%20Auto%20Incremented%20Column%20) to execute the `CHECKIDENT` command through `Sql()`. But I wonder if there are other ways to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework auto increment with starting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967881/entity-framework-auto-increment-with-starting-value)

Comment: @demo That is the method I mentioned in my question, using `CHECKIDENT`. I am asking if we can achieve in other ways. Besides, that article is for EF6, i am asking on EF Core 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, You can use the Fluent API .sample code

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeClass> sample{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("sampleNumber", schema: "shared")
            .StartsAt(10001)
            .IncrementsBy(1);  
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
        .Property(o => o.SomeClassId)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR shared.sampleNumber");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. But according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728226/code-first-entity-framework-inserting-data-with-custom-id/12728384, I think I will need to add an additional line to assign the sequence to the entity, right?